# the behaviour of top: auto; bamboozles me

Tags: css

Hi
I'm really confused about some basics with absolute positioning.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>    
<link href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.0.0/build/cssreset/reset-min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<style>    
#containingBlock {
  position: relative;
  background: green;

}
#abs {
  position: absolute;
  background: blue;
  top: auto;
}  
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="containingBlock">

  <p>foo</p>

  <div id="abs">bar</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

With the markup arranged as above, div#abs does not overlap the foo paragraph.

I know I could make it do this by giving top a value of 0 rather than auto, but since div#containingBlock has no padding, I thought auto and 0 would do the same thing.

However, if the paragraph and div#abs are switched in the source order -to make bar come before foo -top: auto; works exactly as I expected.

Any explanations appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

You didn't really position these elements, you just declared what type of positioning you want to use. In this case, the `auto` value isn't really doing anything, because the #abs element is being placed right where it normally would anyways. If you removed the `top: auto;` segment outright, it would have no effect on the element.

"bar" is not overlapping "foo" because you haven't positioned it to do so. It is contained within the #containingBlock element, and is placed below the block element `<p>` because "foo" takes up a discrete amount of space. You want to override that? Set the `top` or other corresponding position values. To reiterate what others have said, `top:auto` just positions the top of that element as high up as room permits (which is what the element would have done normally).

For future reference, the `auto` value is used for when a parent CSS property overrides the child element's styling. For example let's say you had more complicated code which had a rule to apply a margin to every div within #containingBlock. If you want to change that back to normal, you would include `margin:auto;` in your containingBlock CSS.

Answer (score 5):

When you set position absolute (relative etc) and do not specify a new position for the element, it will be placed where it would normally stay if there was no position:absolute.

Setting it to auto is like not specifying a top position and thus it gets placed under the paragraph where it would normally stay if no special positioning was applied.

Answer (score 2):

it's easy (J/K!), auto and 0 are not the same thing.. well I mean most times they are

`auto` is when the render agent (the browser) attempts to decide what you mean. in the case #1 above the render agent is smart enough to know there is a preceding element, so it allows for it

as you rightly pointed out if you explicitly tell it to go to 0 it will do what it's told

swapping the source order is the same, it's then smart enough to know there is no longer anything preceding it so auto will mean 0 in that case

Comment: I've read time and again that absolute positioning takes things out of the flow. However... it sounds almost as if, when you have `position:absolute`, `auto` acts as if you've said `position:static`. That sound right?

Comment: sitepoint's reference says: "should the value for top be `auto` (the initial value), the top margin edge of the box will be positioned at the top content edge of its containing block." Is this just wrong?

Comment: yes kinda like static or relative, it's just being auto.. Sitepoints ref, is not always right, in the specs it simply says  about TOP _"This property specifies how far an absolutely positioned box's top margin edge is offset below the top edge of the box's containing block. "_ this means if it's 0 it's no offset if it's auto it's going to try and figure out what you mean and it will likely do that by taking into account the bottom border (or is it content) box.. sorry it's hard to explain, but I don't know where Sitepoint gets that and your example shows very clearly what should happen :)

Comment: ^^bottom border/content of preceding in flow element.. that is it's actually the Margin Edge./. e.g. try adding a margin to the `p` in your example.. the auto positioned div will clear the bottom margin..

Comment: Not specifying top/left causes the element to be positioned where it would naturally be if static, but it IS still taken out of document flow because of how content around it interacts with the absolutely positioned content (ie: overlapping).  I'd expect auto to reproduce the behavior of omitting.

Answer (score 0):

Using auto for top (or left) tells the browser to position an element in the exact same way it would if the element had 'position: fixed'.

This jsfiddle demonstrates what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/kUmKW/

Try changing the value of left or top from auto to see what happens.

Comment: wrong, auto means here no positioning https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/CSS/position, though example is good