# Irritating behaviour of positioning: absolute

Tags: html, css, css-position, absolute

As per my knowledge, Absolute positioned element and floated element are removed from the normal flow of html (correct me if i am wrong).

Here's my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fyE4B/2/)

Here's my code:

```
<header> </header>
<div class="content-area">
<div class="left-sidebar"></div>
<div class="main-area"></div>
<div class="right-sidebar"></div>
</div>
<footer> </footer>
```

my css:

```
.content-area {
position: relative;
min-height: 310px;
background-color: #bbb;
}
.left-sidebar {
position:absolute;
float: left;
width: 50px;
height: 100%;
background-color: #abcdef;
}
.right-sidebar {
position: absolute;
right: 0;
width: 50px;
height: 100%;
background-color: #abcdef;
}
```

when i write anything inside my `main-area` why does the right-sidebar slides to down.

Comment: you cant float an absolute element, use right or left

Comment: what advantage it have by floating an absolute element? i can position an absolute element direct by using left, right

Comment: im not following your question? there's no advantage of floating an absolute element because it does **not** work

Comment: @DavidChase oops! sorry i read that wrongly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a `top` property to the side bar

```css
.right-sidebar {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 50px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #abcdef;
}
```

When position `absolute` is specified you are expected to position the element, meaning you must set its `top`, `bottom`, `left` and `right` properties to the values you desire.  If one of these properties is not set the browser positions them, since they will be set to `auto`.

Comment: thanks but can you explain me the reason for that behavior.

Comment: i am not able to understand. can you elaborate. as per my knowledge using position absolute just fix a block to the specified position with respect to parent div(relative positioned). After all this what causes the sidebar to slide down

Comment: Since you did not set the right bar to top:0; it only forces it to hug the right side of the div. You need to set top to 0 if you want the div to hug the top. You did not notice it moving down without it until content was put in because content will push it down, but not any other direction. Once you set top:0; it tells it to stay at the topmost point of the div regardless of content put into the content div. I hope this explanation helps.

Comment: @Shubendra Glad I could help.  This provides some additional context: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5399708/the-behaviour-of-top-auto-bamboozles-me

Comment: @KevinBowersox ok, got 1 more doubt. check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fyE4B/8/ In this i have used float. what causes the right-sidebar to move down in this case.

Comment: @Shubendra That is because block elements expand to fill the width of their container.  So the content area div expands and pushes down the right sidebar.  If you add float left to content area it will shrink to the size of the content (Just the nature of floated divs)

Comment: like absolute positioning floated element are also removed from the normal html flow. by this rule the floated right-sidebar should lie above the content-area div

Answer (score 2):

As they have told you, put `top:0` to fix it.

Ok, the reason:

Check this link: http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-position/#abs-non-replaced-height

The section you are looking for is the 2nd rule: (emphasis added by me)

> If ‘top’ and ‘bottom’ are ‘auto’ and ‘height’ is not ‘auto’, then **set
>   ‘top’ to the static position**, then solve for ‘bottom’.

And that is the reason. Remember, **`top` defaults to `auto` not to `0`**.

Comment: @Glad you could find that in the spec because I sure couldn't! BTW What did you search for to find that?

Comment: I know what you mean, it can be really annoying to find things on the spec. I searched `site:dev.w3.org position absolute` on google, that document is the first result, but then I had to read the index and the title "SIZING AND POSITIONING DETAILS" seemed promising

Comment: @chris ok, got 1 more doubt. check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fyE4B/8 In this i have used float. what causes the right-sidebar to move down in this case.

Comment: @Shubendra that is a complete different thing, using float does not remove something from the normal flow.

Comment: @chris can you please help or point me a link to clear my doubt. i think floated element are also removed from normal flow of html

Comment: @Shubendra this is getting outside the scope of this post, can you create a new question for this?

Comment: yes, sure. after i do i'll post you a link here

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18150765/are-floated-element-really-removed-from-normal-html-flow

Answer (score 0):

Add **top:0;** to your right bar. It should not longer push down after that.