# absolute positioning top:auto has me stumped

Tags: css

I am struggling to understand CSS properties like top:auto for absolute positioning. The definition from MDN has me stumped:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/top

> auto 
>   Is a keyword that represents: 
>   for absolutely positioned elements,
>   the position the element based on the bottom property and treat
>   height: auto as a height based on the content.

Could someone please explain this in beginners terms or point out what I am missing.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5399708/the-behaviour-of-top-auto-bamboozles-me

Answer (score 0):

The auto on position absolute lets the browser calculate the top edge position. This is default.