# Absolutely positioned child's top edge pinned to the bottom edge of its parent that has unknown height?

Tags: html, css

As per the title, which hopefully is intelligible despite being a bit of a mouthful. Just to spell it out a bit more clearly:

This is part of a drop-down menu system. I want a submenu to appear directly below the parent list item. Here is my HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Item 1
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Sub menu 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub menu 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub menu 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Item 2</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The top level `li` elements are of unknown (dynamic) height. I want the child `ul` to appear directly under its parent, with left edges aligned, and the child's top edge pinned to the bottom edge of the parent.

I've been writing CSS for a few years now but realised I have no idea how to do this, or if it is possible... any ideas? Thanks.

**EDIT**

What I am asking for -logically- is very simple. The question is the title, and perhaps I muddied the waters by talking about the specific scenario where I've encountered this. Here is a *much* simpler example of the problem:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

---

```
.parent {
    position: absolute;
    top:200px;
    left:50px;
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px; /* this needs to be dynamic */
    background-color: green;
}

.child {
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: purple;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4ww9h3wu/

I want the top edge of the purple box stuck to the bottom of the green box, while the height of the green box is dynamic. Ya dig?

Comment: Clearly I meant HTML, sorry. Edited. Mind removing the downvote?

Comment: You're making the assumption that I downvoted you.

Comment: Yes. If it wasn't you (you haven't actually disputed it I notice..), my apologies, and could the anonymous downvoter perhaps explain...?

Comment: The drive-by, anonymous downvoters rarely take the time to drop a comment. That said, I can see the reason seeing as you haven't posted any CSS that you tried. As it stands your questions seems a bit broad.

Comment: It didn't seem worth posting CSS, but alright then

Comment: Don't see how it's broad. How many ways could an absposed child be placed flush with the bottom edge of its in-flow, auto-height parent? How much more specific do you have to get? Does the parent have to have an auto-height with a specific amount of padding? Does it have to be floated/non-floated? Does it have to have or not have borders? What about margins? Does the child need to be a specific display type (hint: an absposed box is *always* a block box)? I could go on.

Comment: Yes, I assumed I had been specific enough in my wording not to warrant having to actually post any CSS.

Comment: I've edited this question to make it clearer. And we have an answer. Yay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This usually does it for me...but without *your* CSS it's hard to be sure it will work in your instance.

```
li {
position:relative;
}

li > ul {
position:absolute;
left:0;
top:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that you can't nest anchor tags.  Therefore here is a solution using valid HTML.  Notice the markup change.

By using position absolute but not setting left or top you have a subnav that positions itself directly under the block-level element that precedes it.

(I also have an accessible solution that I have added as a link in the [jsFiddle version](http://jsfiddle.net/haltersweb/r2b1yndv/) of my solution.)

```css
ul, li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul {
  list-style:none;
}
.top-navigation {
    margin: 20px;
}
.top-nav-item {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 120px;
}
.top-nav-item:not(:first-child) {
    margin-left: -.3em;
}
.top-nav-link {
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 5px;
}
.sub-navigation {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    background-color: #fff;
}
.sub-nav-item {
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid green;
    border-top: none;
    padding: 5px;
}
.top-nav-item:hover .sub-navigation {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="top-navigation">
    <li class="top-nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="top-nav-link">Item 1</a>
        <ul class="sub-navigation">
            <li class="sub-nav-item"><a href="#" class="sub-nav-link">Sub menu 1</a></li>
            <li class="sub-nav-item"><a href="#" class="sub-nav-link">Sub menu 2</a></li>
            <li class="sub-nav-item"><a href="#" class="sub-nav-link">Sub menu 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="top-nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="top-nav-link">Item 2</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.  Sed umini. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.  Sed umini. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.  Sed umini. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.  Sed umini. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.  Sed umini. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.  Sed umini.</p>
```

Comment: This is good, thanks. I knew about nesting a tags, not sure how I managed to do that.. 

"By using position absolute but not setting left or top you have a subnav that positions itself directly under the block-level element that precedes it."

I had thought that top/left both defaulted to 0, thereby pinning the element to the top left of the nearest parent with position:absolute or position:relative?

Comment: That is a common misconception. Setting top, left, bottom, and right defines position relative to the first ancestor with position != static.  But by not defining these position styles, the default is auto, therefore the absolutely positioned element, while being taken out of the flow, still anchors itself where it would have landed otherwise.  There is a good stackoverflow article about this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5399708/the-behaviour-of-top-auto-bamboozles-me