# Position:Fixed; is not breaking off the document flow?

Tags: css-position

The green nav bar behind the parent element is positioned as fixed .

And the fixed elements are suppose to break out from the document flow .

But when I am assigning `position:fixed;` [withot any `top,left,right,bottom`], then it should be starting from the top-left pixel of screen.

But no it is starting from a very odd position [it's taking `margin-top:100px`]
[why it is not breaking off from document flow]

Yes parent block [block not element] is having margin of 100px [all sides] Then also

first -> it[green nav] should not care about margins because it should not be in document flow.

Second -> even if its considering the margin from top [of another element], then why it is not considering margin from the left ?

CSS For the Green nav Block -

```
div.nav{
    background-color: green;
    text-align: center;
    height: auto;
    width: 50%;
    margin:0 auto;
    position: fixed; 
}
```

position fixed is not breaking out of document flow 
as it is considering margin-top of the parent element! When 
positioned as relative working expected [within document flow]

CSS for Another block parent whose margin the above navbar is taking -

```
div.parent{
    margin: 100px;
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    border: 3px solid red;
    background-color: skyblue;
    position: relative;
}
```

Green Navbar with position fixed, not breaking off document flow

[image]

Green Navbar with position relative, staying in document flow as expected

[image]

So the real question is why the navbar is not starting from top,left most corner ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [the behaviour of top: auto; bamboozles me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5399708/the-behaviour-of-top-auto-bamboozles-me)

Answer (score 0):

Try this css for stick green navbar on top

```
div.nav{
    background-color: green;
    text-align: center;
    height: auto;
    width: 50%;
    margin:0 auto;
    position: fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:50%;
    transform:translateX(-50%);

}
```

Comment: Thanks bro, but i am demanding a solution out of this situation i can also fix the issue, but the thing is actually i want to know, why this issue is happening .